# How to save the output of tab_model()

Tags: r, sjplot

Data exempel:

```
lme1<- lme(total.fruits ~ rack + nutrient + amd + status,
            random = ~1|reg, method = "ML", data=Arabidopsis)
```

How can I know save the output of the tab_model() function below? The tab_model() function is part of the sjPlot package. Their has to be a nother way than to take a screenshot or?

```
tab_model(lme1)
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add a little bit more information about your goal? Do you want to work with the information programmatically? Embed in a document (what format? Word file?) Functions like `broom.mixed::tidy()` can also capture info

Comment: I just like to save the table as pdf or something similar.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. You could use `webshot` package:
2. With `file` option first save an .html file
3. Then use webshot to make a .png file

See my example with mtcars:

```
library(nlme)
library(sjPlot)
library(webshot)
lme1<- lme(mpg ~ cyl +  disp + hp,
           random = ~1|disp, method = "ML", data=mtcars)

# first save table to html file
tab_model(lme1, file = "plot.html")

# then take this html file and make .png file
webshot("plot.html", "plot.png")
```

Answer (score 10):

you can write the following:

```
library(sjPlot)
tab_model(lme1, file = "YOURTABLENAME.doc")
```

#lme1 can be any model

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).